# Multiprocessing from a class

Tags: python, class, python-multiprocessing

I am new to python programming, and I would like to make a class module for stepper motors. I want to have a function inside the class that makes the stepper motor run forever, and another function to stop it.

```
from steppermotor import stepper
import time
MotorA = stepper(1) # argument is for port, not important
MotorB = stepper(2)
MotorA.forward(2) # stepsize, not important
MotorB.forward(2)
time.sleep(5)
MotorA.stop()
MotorB.Stop()
```

The time.sleep(5) can be replaced with anything. The point is I want to be able to do something else while those two motors are running. Is there a way that I could do this without having to put the subprocessing in the main program, but in the steppermotor.py program? Example with using loops and prints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly you want? you provided another code and you want to do it in another class which you have not described here..

Comment: Add the output of `print(type(stepper))` to your Question.

Comment: It depends what exactly is the thing you want to do. Please elaborate.